# Asp.Net MVC: SSO + AD group?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on

I need to make a web application(asp.net mvc 4) that uses the windows auth(SSO) to authorize users.

But I need to authorize only users which are in special groups(no special sub roles after, it's only to define if we have access or not).

What should I do to achieve this?

I saw there is an "ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider", but I don't know if it fits my needs(SSO, and check for the group).

So what should I do? A custom membership provider? A custom attribute? Will the `[Authorize("MyGroup")]` works?

I never made any auth against an ActiveDirectory registry, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\MyGroup")]
```

Also make sure that you have enabled windows authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: But what do I specify for the auth provider(web.config?)

Comment: You could simply enable windows authentication and remove the role provider section. But if you want to specify it explicitly you could use the [`WindowsTokenRoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx).